# EasyFacebook Android SDK - how do I get user photo?

Tags: android, facebook

I followed this tutorial http://kodefun.junian.net/2011/10/easy-facebook-android-sdk-simple.html  and managed to successfully connect to facebook.

But how do I get user photos? Here's the code so far:

```
...
    public void loginSuccess(Facebook facebook) {
        GraphApi graphApi = new GraphApi(facebook);

        User user = new User();

        try{
            user = graphApi.getMyAccountInfo();

            //update your status if logged in
            graphApi.setStatus("Hello, world!");
        } catch(EasyFacebookError e){
            Log.d("TAG: ", e.toString());
        }

        fbLoginManager.displayToast("Hey, " + user.getFirst_name() + "! Login success!");

        List<Photo> listPh = graphApi.getAllPhotosMy();
    Photo ph = listPh.get(0);
        /// ... how do I get a user photo to drawable or something?


    }
...
```

Any ideas? :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just from messing around in there reference, I would say you would get the persons's ID and the feed that into a from, and then feed that from into the photo again.
I'm no expert on this, but there documentation is your friend.
http://www.easyfacebookandroidsdk.com/doc/index.html